Has this definition of "uniformly discrete" set of points been defined before?
The set $S$ of reciprocals of positive integers is a discrete set, as every point is isolated. However, it is not what I call "uniformly discrete". No matter how small a positive $\epsilon$ you choose, if you "fatten up" the set $S$ by simultaneously putting an $\epsilon$-neighborhood around each point, the neighborhoods will intersect. On the other hand, the set of integers is an infinite set that is uniformly discrete, as you can fatten it up by $\epsilon = 1/3$ without getting intersections. My question is, has this definition been defined and studied before, in some paper or text?

A set $S$ in a metric space is sometimes called $\epsilon$-separated if every pair of distinct points in $S$ has distance $\ge \epsilon$

@Robert Israel: I was about to comment then saw your comment. But I guess I can still follow-up with: A set $S$ in a metric space is sometimes called uniformly isolated if there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that every pair of distinct points in $S$ has distance $\geq \epsilon.$ (moments later) In looking back at the question, it seems the OP already knows about this non-quantified version. There's also the somewhat opposite notion of an $\epsilon$-net.

Here's an example worth having in mind: $$\mathbb{N}\cup{n+{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}}.$$ This is also not uniformly discrete, but unlike $S$ it is complete.
